# i18n localization On Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, xgettext

I have seen the localization package 
I18N (https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n)

and I am trying to find something simliar for Windows Forms. 
is there anythink like it for Windows forms?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic [help]

Comment: Steve, I am looking for a tech solution, for winforms similar to i18n, is that asking for recommendations?

Comment: Well it seems so to me, but if the community doesn't agree with me then you will have your answer. (By the way I don't know of anything that is comparable to that library, the twos environments are too different)

Comment: Ok Steve I think I understood; it seemed that I was promoting the project. That was not my intention and I have no relation to this project. I have found a solution and I believe it would be useful for a few people.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have managed to implement a similar solution for my project by using

https://github.com/neris/NGettext

and the free version of 
https://poedit.net/  to parse my source files and generate/update my .po and .mo files.

Comment: Interesting, and you say that this package works with winforms?

Comment: Yes but I havent found a good solution for data annotations yet. .net Data Annotations use the default resource mechanism that I don't quite like.